# Turning off requestLog

Tags: rest, yaml, dropwizard

We just upgraded our dropwizard version from 0.6.2 or 0.7 and found out that a lot of configurations have changed in .yml file. Although we were able to figure out most of them, we cannot figure out how to turn off the "requestLog". In 0.6.2 we did the following:

```
requestLog:
        # Settings for logging to stdout.
        console:
            # If true, log requests to stdout.
            enabled: false
            # The time zone in which dates should be displayed.
```

But looking at the new [documentation](http://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#request-log):

we do not see any reference to how we can disable the request logs. Any ideas as to how we can achieve our goal of turning off the request log in dropwizard 0.7 ?

Answer (score 19):

The `requestLog` property is now configured under the `server` property. And it looks like the `enabled` property has been removed. You can get around this by setting an empty appenders list. Try something like this:

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http 
    port: 9000
  adminConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 9001
  requestLog:
    appenders: []
```