# How to avoid the console log for each request in a java Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard application, using a servlet, and every request to the servlet is logged to the console like this:

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Oct/2020:07:46:43 +0000] "GET /myServletUrl/subUrl/test?foo=var HTTP/1.1" 200 113 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.5" 3169

I have configured the logging of dropwizard in a yaml, as always, and it works (the logs that I show in the servlet works like the config said). But I can't avoid that strange log... ¿any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Servlet containers usually allow you to bind a logging library, e.g. log4j2 or thelike. There you can define logging appenders. This allows you to redirect messages to various files or outputs (or just to drop them).

Comment: As  I said, I have configured the logging without any problem, with its appenders, etc.... But this strange log its always logged to the console....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. The log is from jetty and dropwizard, not from the server. Is called "requestLog" and you can configure it (and disable too, of course) in the dropwizard configuration.
Like here:
[Turning off requestLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505403/turning-off-requestlog)